# Disnake.py Использование команды только в одном канале с помощью sqlite3 и проверки

Tags: python, база-данных, бот, sqlite3, discord.py

Хочу сделать команду, которая будет ограничивать другие команды на их использование в определённом канале, например: (prefix)disabling say 1029437129778020352, получается чтобы команду say могли использовать только в канале "1029437129778020352".
При использовании команды disabling параметры (say, айди-канала) заносятся в БД(sqlite3):

```
    @commands.command(administrator = True)
async def disabling(guild, ctx, command, channel:disnake.TextChannel):
    global Bot
    db = sqlite3.connect('disabling.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS disabling (guild_id INT, command TEXT, channel INT)')
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT command FROM disabling WHERE channel = '{channel.id}'")
    chan = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT command FROM disabling WHERE command = '{command}'")
    comm = cursor.fetchone()
    if not comm or not chan:
        db = sqlite3.connect('disabling.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO disabling (guild_id, command, channel) VALUES(?, ?, ?)""", (ctx.guild.id, command, channel.id))
        db.commit()
        await ctx.send('**Успешно!\nИспользование команды ограничено этим каналом!**')
    if comm and chan:
        await ctx.send('**Команда уже разрешена для этого канала!**')
        db.commit()
```

[image: sqlite3 bd]

Далее попытался сделать проверку для команд, чтобы при использовании команды проверялось, если для неё ограничение по каналам, если нет, то команду можно использовать везде, если есть, то, если команда использовалась в канале которым она ограничена, команда работала, если же попытались использовать в другом канале, то ничего не происходило.

```
    async def allowed_channel_check():
    def predicate(ctx, channel:disnake.TextChannel):
        db = sqlite3.connect('disabling.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT command FROM disabling WHERE channel = '{channel.id}'")
        chan = cursor.fetchone()
        return ctx.channel.id == chan
    return commands.check(predicate)
```

В этом случае команды можно было использовать везде независимо от ограничений в БД, при этом в терминале выдавало ошибку:

> TypeError: AssistantCommands.allowed_channel_check..predicate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'channel'

Попробовал сделать через ctx.channel.id:

```
    def allowed_channel_check():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        db = sqlite3.connect('disabling.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT command FROM disabling WHERE channel = '{ctx.channel.id}'")
        chan = cursor.fetchone()
        return ctx.channel.id == chan
    return commands.check(predicate)
```

В этом случае бот не реагировал на команды и не выдавал никаких ошибок, то есть ничего не вышло. Прошу помощи...
Вот пример команды, к которой пытался прикрепить ограничение каналом:

```
@commands.command(aliases=['Clear'])
@allowed_channel_check()
async def clear(self, ctx, amount):
    if int(amount) <= 50 and int(amount) >= 1:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount)+1)
        await ctx.channel.send(f'**Сообщения успешно удалены️(`{(amount)}`)**', delete_after=8)
    elif int(amount) <= 0 or int(amount) > 50:
        await ctx.reply('Введите кол-во не меньше 1 и не больше 50!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй посмотреть что то связанное с ивентом [on_message](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api.html#disnake.on_message).
Так же ты в самой команде можешь проверять и сделать что то вроде

```
async def command(interaction):
    closed = 12345# Достаешь айди запрещённых каналов
    if interaction.channel.id not in closed:
        # Что-то
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message('This channel is blocked', ephemeral=True)
```